# How do I pull records RANDOMLY in MySQL using the Ebean ORM?

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by, ebean

I have a requirement where I have to pull a random set of records from a MySQL table and this can be achieved by using the RAND() method inside the SQL query as shown below:

```
SELECT Id
FROM table1
ORDER BY RAND()
```

However I need to implement the same thing now using the Ebean ORM and after reading through the docs I could not find any reference to the Rand() method. Is there an equivalent in Ebean to this? Or anyway I can replicate the same functionality purely through Ebean only?

Available methods for the orderBy query in Ebean: https://ebean.io/docs/query/orderBy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Comment: Not really as this involves writing a raw sql query but I am looking for a way to directly achieve this by calling a method within the Ebean ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use an orderBy expression:

```
.orderBy("RAND()")
```